# JqueryUI confirm dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to add a Jquery UI confirm dialogue but I don't get it...
May be you can help me.

I have a grid and the last line calls the delete of an element with the onClick event...

```
grid.Column(header: loc.GetText("CourseManagement_Action_Delete"), format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("DeleteCourse", new { courseId = item.CourseId })" onclick="ConfirmDelete(item.courseID);"><img id="deleteImage" class="buttonHover" src="@Href("~/Content/images/delete.png")" alt="" style="border: none; position: relative;" /></a></text>, style: "columnWidth")
```

In my Javascript I have have the following

```
    function ConfirmDelete() {
    return confirm("Really delet");
}
```

I want to change it to get a Jquery UI confirm dialogue. How can I realize it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: jQuery UI doesn't have a "confirm dialog". They have plain dialogs, which you can manipulate to behave somewhat like a confirmation dialog by setting their `modal` property to `true`. Check the API documentation for the jQuery UI Dialog widget for more information.

Comment: you may also want to spell **delete** correctly

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the markup for the dialog in your page. Something like this, for example:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete record" style="display:none;">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

And then change your ConfirDelete function to this:

```
function ConfirmDelete(courseID) {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:240,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete item": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                var action = '@Url.Action("DeleteCourse",  new { courseID = "_id_" })'; 
                action = action.replace("_id_", courseID);
                window.location = action;
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
  return false; //The actual submission of the form happens in the click handler for the delete button
}
```

The onClick event handler for the header needs to be changed from

```
 onclick="ConfirmDelete(item.courseID);"
```

To:

```
 onclick="return ConfirmDelete(item.courseID);">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtr8C/1/)

Comment: Hello and thanks for you help. I had an error from my previous tests. so was already   onclick="return ConfirmDelete();"  When I try it with your code I get an Exception in my Html.RenderAction  System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper. Do you have any Idea why?

Comment: @user2286914 unfortunately I don't know why you have such exception but I do know my answer should work as you can verify in the jsfiddle provided. The error you are getting now seems something completely unrelated to this question.

Comment: ok that is strange...bacause if I use the following     function ConfirmDelete() {
        return confirm("Kurs wirklich löschen?");
    }   it works perfect :-(

Comment: so I found it has to do something with the form submit...I do not understand why is it there   $('form').submit();//submit the form

Comment: Post the full stack trace of the error. How are you submitting the form? Is it an Ajax request or a regular postback?

Comment: @user2286914 never mind. Don't post anything. I know what the problem is. Will post an update.

Comment: yeah, thanks for your help, I got the next error..I think it is so close on the gole. I got the error course ID can not be null. Ok so the problem is my originial method is onclick="return ConfirmDelete();">

Comment: you changed the code in the function to  function ConfirmDelete(courseID) {   so there is a course id. the problem is I do not know how to pass the courseID from the top. I only used it in this way  grid.Column(header: loc.GetText("CourseManagement_Action_Delete"), format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("DeleteCourse", new { courseId = item.CourseId })" onclick="return ConfirmDelete();"><img id="deleteImage" class="buttonHover" src="@Href("~/Content/images/delete.png")" alt="" style="border: none; position: relative;" /></a></text>, style: "columnWidth")     sorry I am new in MVC4 Javascript

Comment: You can do this at the top for the onclick event handler: `onclick="return ConfirmDelete(@item.CourseId);"` The whole thing would be like this: grid.Column(header: loc.GetText("CourseManagement_Action_Delete"), format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("DeleteCourse", new { courseId = item.CourseId })" onclick="return ConfirmDelete(@item.CourseId);"><img id="deleteImage" class="buttonHover" src="@Href("~/Content/images/delete.png")" alt="" style="border: none; position: relative;" /></a></text>, style: "columnWidth")

Comment: Great that works perfect..I only had to add '  characters...onclick="return ConfirmDelete('@item.CourseId');"  thank you so much